# Target just the selected class with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following code;

```
$('.time-span').hover(function () {
    $('.leftRadius,.rightRadius').addClass('hovered');
},
function () {
    $('.leftRadius,.rightRadius').removeClass('hovered'); 
});
```

My markup looks like this:

```
<DIV class=leftRadius></DIV>
<A class=time-span ></A>
<DIV class=rightRadius></DIV>

<DIV class=leftRadius></DIV>
<A class=time-span ></A>
<DIV class=rightRadius></DIV>

<DIV class=leftRadius></DIV>
<A class=time-span ></A>
<DIV class=rightRadius></DIV>
```

How can I edit this to just target one '.time-span' class (there are multiple in my document and I can't use id's)?

Thanks

Comment: When you say _just target one '.time-span'_ which one are you trying to target?

Comment: What distinguishes the element from other elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your markup, I think you want to write a hover for specific sections..

```
$('.time-span').hover(function () {
    $(this).prev().addClass('hovered');
    $(this).next().addClass('hovered');
},
function () {
    $(this).prev().removeClass('hovered');
    $(this).next().removeClass('hovered');
});
```

or simply,

```
$('.time-span').hover(function () {
    $(this).prev().toggleClass('hovered');
    $(this).next().toggleClass('hovered');
});
```

Comment: Your answer make more sense than op's question ;) +1 for your eagle eyes

Answer (score 2):

See for ':eq(x)' as css selector:

[:eq() Selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

ex:

```
$('.time-span:eq(0)').hover(function () { //:eq(0) for first occurence
    $('.leftRadius,.rightRadius').addClass('hovered');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use get(index) here too, i.e.:

```
$('.time-span').get(0).hover(function () ...
```

Comment: Works but slower than using direct css selector.